# How non-unique keys results in duplicate records while search, sort or filter in React Lists?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am aware of the fact that while mapping elements for rendering in React, we use "key" so that while re-rendering the changed elements are identified. And hence 'key' must be unique.

But I am curious to know that how actually React renders the elements with the help of "key".

I accidentally encountered a situation where I have received duplicate elements in the list which has same "id".

```
  [
    {id: 101, role: 'developer'},
    {id: 102, role: 'architect'},
    {id: 103, role: 'manager'},
    {id: 102, role: 'architect'},
    {id: 101, role: 'developer'},
  ]
```

I ended up mapping the elements using "id" as "key" .

```
 function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    {id: 101, role: 'developer'},
    {id: 102, role: 'architect'},
    {id: 103, role: 'manager'},
    {id: 102, role: 'architect'},
    {id: 101, role: 'developer'},
  ])
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([...data])

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    if (event?.target?.value) {
      setList([
        ...data.filter((item) => item.role.includes(event.target.value)),
      ])
    } else {
      setList([...data])
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input onChange={handleSearch} />
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div>{item.role}</div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The list rendered fine initially but as I performed "search" operation for elements in the list and manipulated the state to show the searched result , I got undesired response. I checked the state data which I was manipulating, that was fine but rendering of the data on search and after clearing was something like this.

[image]

[image]

If I don't use the key while mapping, it worked fine.

I have fixed this issue by defining a unique identifier for each object in the list and using it as "key".

But I want to understand how did React use "key" for rendering and on using non-unique identifiers as key why it shows up this kind of behavior?

I have gone through the React documentation for [rendering list](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys). I understood the importance of using "key" and how it should be used.
But I still have confusion about the behavior in case key is non-unique.